# Getting dynamic set global variables from one module to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I have two modules that do separate things.

1. `download.py` downloads files to a specific directory
2. `create.py` creates a job (text file) using the downloaded file paths from `download.py`

The files downloaded could be any amount of files. I am able to download the files to a specific location fine, however, when `create.py` creates a job, it depends on the files paths from `download.py`.

I can set a global variable like this in download.py:

```
file_paths = None
```

and when I import it in `create.py` and print it I can see it print out `None`.

```
from download import file_paths
print(file_paths)     # None
```

But this variable `file_paths` never gets updated. I am overriding and setting the variable once download is complete with the file paths, but when I call `create.py` again, it still prints out `None`.

How can I get the updated value?

Comment: We need to see more code that allows us to reproduce this problem, preferably a [mcve]. But it looks like create.py is just importing `file_paths`, I don't see how it executes the code in download.py that actually changes the value assigned to `file_paths`.

Comment: @PM2Ring executing `download.py` downloads the files and stores the path of the downloaded file in the variable `file_paths`. Originally, this value initialized to `None`, after the download is complete then we get the `file_path` updated with the path.

Comment: I can't tell what's going on without seeing the code, but I suspect that create.py isn't running the code in download.py that you need it to run. If you're running download.py independently of create.py, then that will have no effect on create.py.

Comment: That's what I thought, I got it now thanks!